# ParentViewController and subview: setting delegate returns null

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates, subview, pushviewcontroller

I have a `parentViewController` and a `subView`, in `viewWillAppear` in the `parentViewController` I added the `subview` to `self.view` and I set the `delegate` of subview to `self`. When I'm trying to use the delegate in the subview to `push` another view controller it does't work, I checked the value of delegate and it got "null".

My Main idea: when the user clicks on a button in the subview, I need to push another viewController using the `navigationController` of the parentViewController.

Here is my code

```
//parentViewController.h 

#import "mysubView.h"

@interface parentViewController : UIViewController <mysubViewDelegate>
.
.//Some properties here
.
@end
```

In the implementation file:

```
//parentViewController.m 

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    mysubView *myView;

    //GlobalObjects is to load the file in a certain language
    myView = [[GlobalObjects loadNibNamed:@"mysubView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    //Print myView.delegate gets the correct value here
    myView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:myView];

}
.
.
.
-(void)pushViewControllerUsingDelegate:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

In mysubView.h:

```
//mysubView.h

@protocol mysubViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)pushViewControllerUsingDelegate:(UIViewController *)viewController;

@end

@interface mysubView : UIView< UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
}

@property (nonatomic , retain) id <mysubViewDelegate> delegate;

-(IBAction)ButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender;


@end
```

In mysubView.m

```
@implementation mysubView
@synthesize delegate;
.
.
.

-(IBAction)ButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    newViewController *newController = [[newViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"newViewController" bundle:nil];

    //Here is my problem in this line .. self.delegate is null here
    [self.delegate pushViewControllerUsingDelegate:newViewController];
}

-(void)pushViewControllerUsingDelegate:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self.delegate pushViewControllerUsingDelegate:viewController];
}
@end
```

Comment: Start classes with a Capital letter, so `ParentViewController`, `newViewController`, ...

Comment: How many instances of `mysubView` do you create?

Comment: My classes are already start with Capital letter, I'm sorry for that but when I wrote this question i used small letters

Comment: I created only one instance of mysubView @Wain

Comment: @Sawsan did you find an answer to this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
myView = [[GlobalObjects loadNibNamed:@"mysubView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Use mysubView  instead of GlobalObjects like as below

```
myView = [[mysubView loadNibNamed:@"mysubView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Please use Capital letter when you create new class.this is only convention but you should follow it.

Comment: how does that even remotely answer the question ?!